# Website not updating - no cache plugins active!

Tags: updates, cache, automatic-updates

I've a problem with my WordPress website getting updated after I make changes to its code:

I'm using phpStorm with auto-save, running the website on WAMP, locally.
Therefore, right after I right new code, the file in which I write the code in should be updated, and the website quickly after that.

Yet the website doesn't update.

I'm not using **any** cache plugins, and in my browser, Chrome, I disabled caching.

Also, it does get updated, but only after I make changes to the website - like disable and then enable again a plugin - so it can store new cache, but for some reason, it doesn't do it automatically, and keeps using old cache when I don't make any changes via the dashboard.

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: Hi. You said you aren't using any cache plugin, but then you mentioned about storing a new cache.

Comment: I meant that WordPress does that somehow.

I haven't configured for it to do it, and I don't know of anything that I've done that could cause this behavior.

Comment: Have your searched your `wp-content` folder for any cache file/folder?

Comment: I haven't. I'll check and update.

Comment: I went to `wp-content` and I found a cache folder.
I deleted all of what was inside of it - and I did see a cached file of the home page of my website (the only one that I was working on) - and I deleted it, too.

Deleting the content of the folder didn't change anything, and after changing the code and refreshing the page, it didn't render based on the new code. Also, no new files were created in the cache folder.

Comment: Well there is definitely some sort of caching going on. Either a plugin like JetPack, or a server-side cache. [This](https://codex.wordpress.org/I_Make_Changes_and_Nothing_Happens) article can be useful in your case.

Comment: Is there a chance that there's some update limitation from PHP or WordPress? I've also noticed that after some time, it does update on its own.

Comment: You mentioned that you are using WAMP, so it might be causing the issue. Try disabling it by setting `opcache.enable 0` and `opcache.enable_cli=0` in your `php.ini` file. Also you might need to remove these 2 lines in your `httpd.conf` file `Include conf/pagespeed.conf` and `Include conf/pagespeed_libraries.conf`

Comment: I did what you said, and it didn't help. :\

Again, the website was able to be updated after some time, alone, but what I did didn't affect it.

Comment: Did you restart WAMP after changing those values? I can't think of any other cache.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to expire header. Try to add a time less than 180 seconds

ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 180 seconds"

either in server or htaccess.